# awk and sed challenge: adjust the text width

Tags: sed, awk

So let's see how can we do this: trim the text width within a certain value, say, 10.
For lines longer than 10, break it into multiple lines.

Example:
A text file:

> ```
> 01234567
> 01234567890123456789abcd
> 0123
> ```

should be changed to:

> ```
> 01234567
> 0123456789
> 0123456789
> abcd
> 0123
> ```

So how can we do it using sed or awk as short as possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or, marginally shorter (than Jonathan Dursi's answer):

```
sed -e 's/.\{10\}/&\
/g' text.file
```

```
sed -e 's/.\{10,10\}/&\
/g' text.file
```

Tested on MacOS X 10.6.4, which does not use GNU sed.

Comment: Nice -- learn something new every day!  Didn't know about the \{m,n\} business.

Comment: In fact, it looks like this can be shortened even further; if it has to match exactly n characters, you don't have to specify the second number:  "$ sed -e 's/.\{10\}/&\n/g' foo.txt"  works too, or with the quoted newline for non-gnu seds.

Comment: @Jonathan - yup; the 10,10 was a later change from 1,10 which didn't work as well, and I forgot to eliminate the repeat.

Answer (score 5):

Use the proper tool for the job...

```
fold -w 10
```

Comment: But where's the *challenge* in that... `fold` is part of POSIX and should be pretty wide available.

Comment: still great to know this tool

Comment: I've tried this with a text with Spanish characters (e.g. á¿¡) and the characters where not output well. Using the sed command did. Give it yourselves a go. I just tried with a file containing the line "á¿¡012345" without quotes, and fold -w 5 > blah. Maybe a fold issue?

Comment: @rturrado: Unfortunately, `fold` is not Unicode-aware. Bugs have been filed and patches have been created, but it's still broken.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sed -e 's/\(..........\)/\1\\n/g' foo.txt
```

or, if that doesn't work (eg, don't have a sufficiently new gnu sed), just insert a newline and make sure it's quoted:

```
$ sed -e 's/\(..........\)/\1\\
/g' foo.txt
```

You can pretty much transliterate that into awk, too:

```
$ awk '{ gsub(/........../, "&\n" ) ; print}' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In `awk` with a variable width:

```
awk -v WIDTH=5 '{ gsub(".{"WIDTH"}", "&\n"); printf $0 }; !/\n$/ { print "" }'
```

The final statement prevents the printing of extra newlines when the line is an exact multiple of the maximum line width.